# Scala : Retry with try/catch for exception handling

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, try-catch, user-defined-functions

I am trying to add a retry logic for JSON conversion. When converting an object to json, I am retrying for 3 times if there is any exception. I am doing :

```
   var mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  intializeMapper( )

  def intializeMapper() = {
    // jackson library does not support seralization and deserialization of
    // of scala classes like List and Map, this is needed to support it
    mapper.registerModule( DefaultScalaModule )
    // enables parsing of NaN. Enabling it here as JsonUtil class currently in
    // use supports it.
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true )
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  } 


 def getPersonRDD(result: DataFrame): RDD[(String, String)] = {

    val finalValue = result.rdd.map({
      r =>
        val customerId = r.getAs[String](CUSTOMER_ID)
        val itemId = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]](ITEM_ID)
        val itemName = r.getAs[Map[String, Int]](ITEM_NAME)


        val person = Person(itemId, itemName)

        val jsonString = toJson(person)

        (customerId, jsonString)

    })

    return finalValue
  }

  def fromJson(json: String, clazz: Class[_]) = {
    mapper.readValue(json, clazz)
  }

  def toJson(value: Any): String = {

    var jsonString: String = " "
    jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(value)

    try {
      fromJson(jsonString, clazz)
      return jsonString
    } catch {
      case Exception => {

        publishMetrics(PARSING_EXCEPTION, 1.0)
        val result = util.Try(retry() {
          jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(value)
          val features = fromJson(jsonString, clazz)
        })

        result match {
          case util.Success(value) => jsonString

          case util.Failure(error) => {
            log.error("Error while parsing JSON " + jsonString)
            return jsonString
          }

        }

      }
    }

  }

  // Returning T, throwing the exception on failure
  @annotation.tailrec
  def retry[T](n: Int = 3)(fn: => T): T = {
    util.Try {
      fn
    } match {
      case util.Success(x) => x
      case _ if n > 1 => retry(n - 1)(fn)
      case util.Failure(e) => throw e
    }
  }

case class Person(itemId: Map[String, Int], itemName: Map[String, Int]) extends Serializable
```

Is this correct ? I am new to Scala. Can someone suggest me if there is any better way for achieving this ? Is there predefined retry logic available in Scala ? The reason I am trying to add retry logic for JSON conversion is due to Jackson version I use(which I can't change for now), sometimes my writeValueAsString results in incomplete JSON.

Comment: You’re parsing Json, it is deterministic. Why would you expect another time through to get a different result?

Comment: Could you briefly sketch what the 'mapper' is and what it is doing? Does it have the capability to somehow correct invalid json input? If not, what's the point of retrying?

Comment: @NathanHughes because of JacksonJackson-databind = 2.6.x;
                Jackson-core = 2.6.x;
                Jackson-annotations = 2.6.x;
                Jackson-module-scala = 2.6.5; my conversion results in partial json and this is very non deterministic.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin The input is just a case class which I am converting to JSON

Comment: How strange. Could it be this data frame you’re reading from is populated lazily or something?

Comment: @NathanHughes It works fine with 2.8.x but due to some dependency I need to use 2.6.x which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retry function seems correct. The only flaw I can think of is that if you expect something would fail it's better just make the return type `Try[T]`, so you can handle it outside in the scala way.

Here is one of my implementation:

```
def retry[T](n: Int)(block: => T): Try[T] = {
  val stream = Stream.fill(n)(Try(block))
  stream find (_.isSuccess) getOrElse stream.head
}
```